# How do I override the insert command of a MySQLdataadapter to use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with C#

Tags: c#, mysql, dataset

My application is extracting data from one DB and inserting the results into a different DB using MySqlDataAdapters and DataSets. I created a unique key in the target DB and want to update values in cases where I recalculated them.

I am hoping to use the data adapter Update method to handle this since there is a variable number of rows to INSERT/UPSERT each time. I also want the update to be as fast as possible since this is a repeating process.

If I exclude the possibility of update and just do inserts my code is functional as follows:

```
 ... // dsDSErrors is the dataset returned from my initial query
  MySqlCommand cmdLocal = new MySqlCommand(queryLocal, myLocal);
  MySqlDataAdapter daLocal = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmdLocal);
  daLocal.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
  DataSet dsLocal = new DataSet();
  daLocal.Fill(dsLocal);
  foreach (DataRow drError in dsDSErrors.Tables[0].Rows)
  {
      DataRow curRow = dsLocal.Tables[0].NewRow();
      foreach (DataColumn hdr in dsDSErrors.Tables[0].Columns)
          curRow[hdr.ColumnName] = drError[hdr.ColumnName];
      dsLocal.Tables[0].Rows.Add(curRow);
  }
  MySqlCommandBuilder bldDSErrors = new MySqlCommandBuilder(daLocal);
  daLocal.Update(dsLocal);
```

I understand that I can use daLocal.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand(insert command) but was wondering if it is necessary to then loop through the results and add them  to the VALUES section of the insert statement or if there was a method I'm not aware of that will handle this.

Barring built in functionality, I assume its best to use string builder to build up the insert query with all my values rows?

Comment: Not your answer, but perhaps you could remove the inner loop using [LoadDataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.loaddatarow(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Steve - thanks for pointing that out. Looks like the array input for that function would require some formatting work that would eliminate any gains made by removing the loop.

Comment: `dsLocal.Tables[0].LoadDataRow(drError.ItemArray);` not good?

Comment: That was my first try, For some reason the array is not in the order I would expect, plus it tries to update the ID column which is Auto increment. I was able to just build the SQL using string builder and avoid the creation of the local data adapter and data set. Building SQL feels less elegant than using the MySQL connector types but the missing ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE functionality seems an oversight in the connector.